# Erro Nan no array com objetos

Tags: javascript

```
var armazenamento = [];
armazenamento.push({nome: nomeproduto, valor: + preco})
for(i in armazenamento){
   total =+ armazenamento[valor: i]
   i++
   }
console.log(total)
troco = PagoCliente - total
```

Criei um array chamado de armazenamento e adicionei nome e valor a ele, em seguida eu estou tentando armazenar todos os valores em uma variável chamada total para depois exibir quanto de troco deve dar para o cliente. So que ao solicitar o troco ele esta aparecendo Nan

Comment: Romulo, seu exemplo está executando? Pois essa linha ```total =+ armazenamento[]``` nem permite eu executar o código.

Comment: acabou q nao botei aqui, mas era pra sair assim: total =+ armazenamento[{valor: i}]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitua o seu `for in` por um `for of`:

```
for (let i of armazenamento) {
   total =+ i.valor;
}
```

O `for in` itera sobre as propriedades de um objeto, enquanto o `for of` itera sobre uma `array`, `map` etc... E como sua variável `armazenamento` é um array, o `for of` resolve o seu problema.

> Veja mais sobre esses `for` nas documentações:
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

---

Seu código completo vai ficar mais ou menos da seguinte forma (declarei algumas variáveis para funcionar):

```js
//Variáveis declaradas para efeitos de teste
let total = 0;
let PagoCliente = 69;
let nomeproduto = "Xisto";
let preco = 13;

var armazenamento = [];

armazenamento.push({nome: nomeproduto, valor: + preco});

for (let i of armazenamento) {
   total =+ i.valor;
}

console.log(total);

troco = PagoCliente - total;

console.log(troco);
```

Comment: Acho que o seu ficou melhor que o meu :)

Answer (score 2):

Você também pode utilizar o método **[reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)** para fazer o que deseja, ele é muito indicado quando necessitamos manipular valores em arrays:

```js
var armazenamento = [];
var PagoCliente = 50;
var troco;

armazenamento.push({
  nome: 'produto 01',
  valor: 10
})

armazenamento.push({
  nome: 'produto 02',
  valor: 5
})

var total = armazenamento.reduce((anterior, atual) => {
    return anterior + atual.valor;
},0)

troco = PagoCliente - total;

console.log('Total: ', total);
console.log('Troco: ', troco);
```

Comment: Boa! Esqueci desse exemplo :D